# Developing a website on top of RESTFul APIs

Tags: rest, api, jboss

we're developing kind of a social network.
We first focused on mobile applications and thus we developed our own API (REST) using jboss as application server and everything is fine.

Now we are beginning the development of a website. We decided to build such website on top on the API we already have, so we won't have to worry about the database management.

My question is: what approach should I follow?

1. client-side calls (using ajax)
2. server-side calls (using e.g. php, python) to dynamically generate the html page

Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks,
Andrea

Comment: Totally depends on what you want to achieve. Good examples of websites that use client side API calls (to themselves) are PivotalTracker and Trello - server side calls might slow down your page load a little...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like a mixed approach.

Direct client side calls into your REST layer will have issues with Authentication & Authorization.

So you need to have a server-side Facade that validates application session and then allows the calls to pass through to your backend.

This layer can employ pagination kind of logic if the REST APIs have them missing.

Sometimes an UI action would require you to manipulate the data structure or multiple REST calls to create the resulting view. Direct one-to-one mapping of UI action to backend REST calls may not be possible. There also this facade helps make the APIs more UI friendly.

Finally - for some static / cachable HTML fragments your server can generate the view from REST layer and cache it for faster serving.

So in summary

Use node.js or playframework kind of AJAX based UI to build the UI layer.

But to use a Facade that orchestrates, aggregates, transforms, authenticate, authorize the UI calls before hitting the REST layer - to keep the UI experience simpler.